# How can I properly set a condition for an specific space in array?

Tags: c++, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm Developing an small app for practice purposes in C++, I actually suceeded developing this algorithm without using arrays, but right now I want to do it using an Array. The program should accept four grades 2 of 15 points practices (First and third value), two of 20 points (Second and fourth values) and one of 30 points. this is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int grades[5];
    int i; 
    int sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        cin >> grades[i];

        sum+=grades[i];

        if(grades[0]>15||grades[1]>20){

            cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
            break;

        }else if(grades[2]||grades[3]){

            cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
            break;

        }if(grades[4]>30){

            cout <<"ERROR"<<endl;
            break;
        }

    }   
}
```

The issue here is that it should not be printing Error on console and break it from continuing, only if the condition is met, at this point if I input values even within the condition's grace, it prints out "Error" and stops.

I'm not really looking for someone to solve this issue, I'm looking to know what I'm doing wrong without getting someone to solve it for me, in proper words, I'm looking for tips/hints.

Comment: "*The program should accept four grades ... 2 ... two ... and one*" - Perhaps you mean that it should accept **five** grades?

Comment: You probably want your `for` loop to end after the `sum+=...` line. No need to do all the checks on every iteration...

Comment: You put the error checking inside your loop. This means you check for errors five times. Even worse look at your checks, for instance you check `if(grades[4]>30)`, you do this each time round the loop even when *you haven't entered a value for grades[4] yet*. You only need to check for errors once, so put the error checking code after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This line here

```
     }else if(grades[2]||grades[3]){

            cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
            break;

     }
```

will cause your error to display at any time your elements at indices 2 or 3 are non zero. You dont initialise your array elements so it is quite possible that the values are nonzero when your loop starts. To ensure that they are not, you could assign zero to all elements before you start. I am not sure what your code is trying to do, but when the user enters anything other than zero for the `cin` at `i = 2` and `i = 3` your loop will break with error output (assuming that the first `if` confition in your `if-else` block is not satisfied but if that condition was satisfied your loop would also exit anyway)

Comment: int grades[5] = { 0 }; If you want to do as mathematician1975 says.

Comment: Thank you Mathematician and Science_Fiction.

Comment: @OmarPérez If this answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the accepted answer.